# Timelapse without using storage for jpegs: pipe the raspistill output directly to mencoder

Tags: camera, video

I want to make a timelapse with my Pi, but rather than storing thousands of images on my small SD card and then spend hours `mencoder`'ing the result, I'd like to pipe the `raspistill -tl` output (if possible) into mencoder, and get the resulting compressed video when I stop the process.

Since I plan to take 1 picture every 5s, I figure there's plenty of time to append that image to the mencoder video between shots.

Is is possible?

I tried a simple script but have an error:

```
$ raspistill -a 12 -tl 1000 -t 10800000 -o - | mencoder - -nosound -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:aspect=16/9:vbitrate=8000000 -vf scale=1920:1080 -o timelapse.avi -mf type=jpeg:fps=30
MEncoder SVN-r37379 (C) 2000-2015 MPlayer Team
Reading from stdin...
success: format: 0  data: 0x0 - 0x0
libavformat version 56.25.101 (internal)
Cannot seek backward in linear streams!
Seek failed
Cannot seek backward in linear streams!
Seek failed
Cannot seek backward in linear streams!
Seek failed
```

I suppose a list of JPG is not exactly what mencoder gets from the input. Any guru here to help me?

*edit*

With a separate command invocation:

```
raspistill -a 12 -tl 1000 -t 10000 -o - > test.raw # takes 10 images across 10 s
mencoder test.raw -nosound -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:aspect=16/9:vbitrate=8000000 -vf scale=1920:1080 -o timelapse.avi -mf type=jpeg:fps=30
```

This produces a valid video, so there's something in the pipe that doesn't work correctly.

Comment: `I suppose a list of JPG is not exactly what mencoder gets from the input`. I suppose you're right. Try piping it to a file to see what you're getting (e.g. `raspistill -a 12 -tl 1000 -t 10800000 -o - > output`. Then open the output file and see what's there. I don't think it will solve anything, but it may help you figure out what's happening. If piping output doesn't work you could try having it save to the SD, feed the image to `mencoder`, and delete it. Sorry I'm not a guru!

Comment: FWIW it works with this, I can have that file sent to mencoder and it can encode the timelapse. So it *should* work with a pipe but it doesn't.

Comment: If mencoder is expecting the input to be seekable, then the file will be but the pipe obviously won't. If that's the issue then in the second case, trying `cat test.raw | mencoder - -nosound ... -o timelapse.avi` should also fail. However, if that's the case I'm not sure there's anything you can do about it.

Comment: I can understand that, but then would it be possible to have some sort of "rolling buffer" where raspistill can deposit the last, say, 10 or 50 images and let mencoder seek in there? I'd really like to not screw my SD card taking so many pictures, plus having the ability to have a "rolling" timelapse that could last for months.

Comment: @Gui13 On a hunch try adding `-cache 1024` as an argument to `mencoder` (or perhaps a larger number). This is supposed to solve the same error with `mplayer`. `mencoder` also accepts the cache option and your comment about the buffer made me think this just might work. Sorry my Pi is giving me trouble otherwise I'd try it myself first.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the exact same thing. After fiddling around with terminal piping and getting rather mixed results (incomplete files, dropped frames, large filesize, etc.), I found that the Python `picamera` module (preloaded on Raspbian) can give excellent H.264 timelapse videos easily.

For the Camera module v1, PiCamera allows setting the video framerate as low as one frame per 6 seconds. For the Camera module v2, the framerate can go down to one frame per 10 seconds. These should cover most use cases.

The bonus is that all processing is done on the GPU, so this requires almost no CPU time.

Example:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from fractions import Fraction
camera = PiCamera()
try:
        camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)  # 1080p is the max resolution of the H.264 encoder
        camera.framerate = Fraction(1, 3) # One frame every 3 seconds
        camera.start_recording('output.mp4', format='h264', quality=23)
        camera.wait_recording(300)        # Time of recording, in seconds
        camera.stop_recording()
finally:
        camera.close()
```